# Testing dock's USB 3.0 speed

Tags: usb

An older HP2560P laptop that is compatible with a docking station sporting USB3.0 (SS).  It is unclear if it realize USB 3.0 speeds because I think the dock was designed for the HP2570P.

Seeking a clever (simple and cost effective) test that could be run on the USB 3.0 (>1GB/Sec) and 2.0 ports (<1GB/Sec).  I am assuming that if I observe throughput of > 1GB per sec, then the laptop is USB 3.0 compatible (from the dock only).  I expect to have access to a SSD and enclosure to support the test in the near future.  Suggestions to measure speed are appreciated.  Thank you